# Conceder multiples permisos para android Marshmallow ( Android 6.0 )

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permisos, android-permissions

voy directo al problema. 
Quiero pedir multiples permisos en celulares de android 6.0 o de mayor version en Android Studio

Y me pasa que si bien porgramo para que los pida a todos solo pide el primero.. codigo

*IMPORTS*

```
import static android.Manifest.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION;
import static android.Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE; 
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS;
```

*MAIN*

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Permis();
        }
```

*Funcion para asignar permisos*

```
private void Permis() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if ((checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                    (checkSelfPermission(CHANGE_CONFIGURATION) ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                    (checkSelfPermission(MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS) ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                    (checkSelfPermission(WRITE_SETTINGS) ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                Toast.makeText(tuneActivity.this, "Permiso concedido  anteriormente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


if ((shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))||   (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CHANGE_CONFIGURATION)) || (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS)) || (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_SETTINGS))){

                DialogoAlerta();

            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,  CHANGE_CONFIGURATION, MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, WRITE_SETTINGS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
            }


        }
    }
```

*Funcion DialogoAlerta*

```
private void DialogoAlerta() {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogo=new AlertDialog.Builder(tuneActivity.this);
        dialogo.setTitle("Permisos desactivados");
        dialogo.setMessage("Debe aceptar los permisos para poder definir un  tono como ringtone o sonido de notificacion");
        dialogo.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,  CHANGE_CONFIGURATION, MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, WRITE_SETTINGS},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

*onRequestPermissionsResult*

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            `super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);`
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[3] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) { 

            Toast.makeText (tuneActivity.this,"Permiso concedido",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText (tuneActivity.this,"Permiso no concedido",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;

    }
}
}
```

Y como les decia, solo me pide un permiso el cual es WriteExternalStorage, es decir el primero y cuando entra en el onRequestPermissionsResult me retorna claramente que no se han otorgado los permisos correctamente ya que no los verifica todos porque solo me aparece el cuadro de dialogo para permitir el primero, espero su ayuda chicos desde ya gracias ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como decia @Elenasys♦ los unicos permisos que necesitaba eran los de escribir en la memoria y los de escribir en la configuracion siendo este ultimo imposible de pedir por riesgos que concidera android.

Entonces la solucion para pedir los permisos de Write SystemConfig

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        retVal = Settings.System.canWrite(this); //esto nos retornara si ya tenemos los permisos obtenidos o no
if(retVal){  
            Toast.makeText(this, "Todo bien pasa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            //pedimos los permisos, pero como no podemos tenemos que llevar al usuario a las configuraciones donde estan los permisos de WriteConfiguration para que el mismo nos valide
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Y asi logramos hacer lo que queremos ;), claramente puede tener variaciones en el codigo dependiendo de como y para que lo quieramos utilizar. si se les ocurre algo mas eficiente o prolijo posteenlo.

Answer (score -1):

Tu código es correcto, para sistema operativo android 6.0 o posterior es correcto la forma de requerir los permisos pero en este caso, **no es suficiente solo importar las clases, debes agregar los permisos dentro de tu  archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` con esto debes poder visualizar el dialogo sin problema.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otro punto importante, los permisos :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

**son permisos que únicamente se conceden para aplicaciones de sistema.**

Comment: Genial, pero entonces no tengo forma de poder hacer cosas como poner un sonido como ringtone o sonido de notificacion ? porque tenia entendido que para ponerlo necesitaba esos permisos.

Comment: porque tenia entendido que para ponerlo necesitaba esos permisos. utilizo RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(tuneActivity.this, types, newUri); para setear ringontes y funciona en todos los androids excepto desde los 6.0 que crasheaba y me tiraba error justamente de permisos

Comment: osea el archivo lo puedo crear, pero no hay forma de ponerlo automaticamente como ringtone o notificacion sin tener permisos de write settings no?

Comment: Para crear una aplicación de sistema tienes que poder crear la aplicación en la partición del sistema lo cual requiere permisos ROOT!.

Comment: Si usas algunas funcionalidades que requieren los permisos para app de sistema y no es una app de sistema obtendras errores.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias, tengo una solucion que se adapta bastante bien a lo que propongo igual, ahora en un rato la posteo pero basicamente se basa en desplegar el apartado de configuraciones donde estan las apps del sistema y que el user pueda darle permisos a la mia

Comment: Con Settings.System.canWrite() y todo lo relacionado

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.